# Control webpack verbosity when programmatically starting vue-cli-service serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to run `vue-cli-service serve` from inside a Node.js application like this:

```javascript
const Service = require('@vue/cli-service');
const service = new Service(process.cwd());
service.init("development");
service.run('serve').then(({ server, url }) => {
  console.log("started server on " + url);
});
```

And it works.

```
$ node e2e.js
INFO  Starting development server...
40% building 130/136 modules 6 active ...node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js??ref--13-0!.../ui/src/js/config/Product.js...
. . .
. . .
started server on http://localhost:8080/
```

But when I do it in `production` mode (change `service.init("development")` to `service.init("production")`), I don't see the webpack "building" progress anymore.

```
$ node e2e.js
INFO  Starting development server...
started server on http://localhost:8080/
```

Hence my question: how to start a Vue server in production mode, but keep webpack progress printed to the console?

Comment: I am baffled by the fact that this isn't documented anywhere in Vue docs. Spent like 6 hours to write a script that does the same job and then found this. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress is reported by Webpack's [`ProgressPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/progress-plugin/), which Vue CLI [inserts only for non-production and non-test builds](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/6f085d3/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/dev.js#L19-L23) (since 3.x).

You could enable this plugin in [`<root>/vue.config.js`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) with `devServer.progress=true` (currently [undocumented](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver)):

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    progress: true  // always show progress (even in production mode)
  }
}
```

Or in your `e2e.js`, you could insert the `ProgressPlugin` into the `Service` instance's `webpackChainFns[]` *after* `init()`:

```js
service.init("production")
service.webpackChainFns.push(config => {
  config
    .plugin("progress")
    .use(require("webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin"))
})
```